# Use a different class for UIViewController's View property

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, initialization, subclass, loadview

By default UIViewController's view property is a UIView instance. Is it possible to change it to instead be an instance of MyView, a subclass of UIView, without having to override the -view getter to return an instance of MyView? With storyboards this is very easy and can be done in the identity inspector- surely there must be an equivalent and official programmatic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the simple answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893601/where-can-i-specify-which-uiview-is-used-for-the-view-property-of-a-uiviewcontro?rq=1) where I simply have to override -loadView